# Prestashop adding product from another app to my cart

Tags: javascript, prestashop

I developed a landing page with native html and css and I used prestashop webservice api to load all my products. Now I need to develop "add to my cart" button without authentication require, the same one on the shop. I didn't found the solution on the webservice api, is there any possibility to do that please?

Answer (score 0):

You can get inspiration from this module:
https://github.com/PrestaShop/ps_buybuttonlite/

I suggest you check this file:
https://github.com/PrestaShop/ps_buybuttonlite/blob/dev/controllers/front/RedirectManager.php